# Is it efficient to use UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer to make curved edges on IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have to make only top two corners curved for UILabel, so I have done like this after little exploration..

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;

maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:label.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = label.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
label.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Is it efficient to do? In one forum they mentioned don't use this more than once for efficient purpose. If so what should I do? I need in few places. Thanx.

Comment: Guys above code is working fine, My question is, efficient or not? Will it make my application slow? or Any other drawback?

Comment: Well, if you do it in several places once, it's not a problem. If you'd do it in a loop, then I guess it would not be efficient. Why don't you start the app with Instruments and see it for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to do this - it's no more resource-intensive than creating a bitmap of comparable size and drawing a few curves on it. When they say not to use it more than once, they mean don't use it more than once within the lifespan of the object (i.e. call it just once when you load it). You could use this for every label in your app (in an override of `initWithFrame:`, for example) and you'd be fine.